# React - value of this inside componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that I am creating like this. But the value of `this` that I am getting inside `getInitialState`, `componentDidMoun` and `render` seems to be different.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: () => {
        console.log('Inside getInitialState')
        console.log(this)
        return {
            title: 'Heading'
            , content: 'Text'

        }
    }
    , componentDidMount: () => {
        console.log('Inside componentDidMount')
        console.log(this)
    }
    , render: function () {
        console.log('Inside render')
        console.log(this)
        return <div>
            <Intro />
            <SectionText heading = {this.state.title} text = {this.state.content}/>
        </div>
    }
    , getArticle: id => {
        articleStore.getArticle(id)
    }
    , handleChange: () => {
        this.setState(articleStore.getState())
    }
})
```

[image: console log]

I can see the expected props, states, functions inside render's `this` but not in the case of the other two methods.
Is this expected ?? How do I access my react component's properties, states, functions ??

Comment: Did you know that the value of `this` is different when you use arrow functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions Why are you using arrows in one but not the other?

Comment: thanks .. stupid me :D

Comment: you can add that as the answer if you want, and i'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your desired `this` within ES6 arrow functions

https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/